# find point on line tangent to circle with known location and radius

Tags: trigonometry

i have a line with a start and end point (a,b). i also have a circle with a centerPoint (x,y) and a radius R. how can i determine where (and if) the line touches the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the circle have cente $c = (c_x, c_y)$ and radius $R$.  Let the segment join points $p = (p_x,p_y)$ to $q = (q_x, q_y)$.  The circle has equation

$$
  (x - c_x)^2 + (y - c_y)^2 = R^2
$$

While the line containing the segment has equation
$$
  y = p_y + (x - p_x) \frac{ q_y - p_y }{q_x - p_x}
$$

Now you have the following system.
$$
\begin{cases}
  (x - c_x)^2 + (y - c_y)^2 = R^2 \\
  y = p_y + (x - p_x) \frac{ q_y - p_y }{q_x - p_x}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Solve it by replacing the $y$ in the first equation with the right hand side of the second equation.  You know have a second degree equation in $x$.  Solve it : if you have two solutions, the line cut the circle, if you have one, the line is tangent to the circle and if you have none, the line and the circle do not touch each other.

To find back the corresponding $y$'s, use the second equation, by replacing $x$ with the solutions you found.

Now make sure your solution are indeed on the segment and not on the line going through the segment but outside of the segment.  That is, make sure that $x$ is between $[p_x,q_x]$ (or $[q_x,p_x]$), and $y$ is between $[p_y, q_y]$ (or $[q_y,p_y]$).

Comment: thank you, ill try this. I'll let you know if it works out

Comment: I made a small mistake in the equation of the line; corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a circle with center in the origin $(0,0)$ and aline segment between points $a$ and $b$. Define the vector $v=b-a$. If

$$\langle a,v\rangle \cdot \langle b,v\rangle >0.$$

then the line segment is *not* tangent to the circle. Otherwise compute the vector

$$w=a-\langle a,v\rangle\cdot\frac{v}{\|v\|^2}.$$

The line segement is a tangent if and only if $\|w\|=R$.